# Change max length of link field link text

Tags: 8, navigation, configuration

In order to modify the length of a file field description field I put the following line in settings.php:

`$config['file.settings']['description']['length'] = 512;`

Now I want to do the same for the link field. How can I change the max length of the link text (without patching the module)?

I think the problem is that FileWidget.php gets the length from the configuration

`'#maxlength' => $config->get('description.length')`

whereas it is hardcoded in LinkWidget.php:

`'#maxlength' => 255`

Answer (score 2):

If you go for module then you can check [Maxlength](https://www.drupal.org/project/maxlength) module.

> Maxlength allows you to set maximum length of any field on any form
>   making use of the form API. This includes fields created using the UI.
>   (Example: any text field on a node)

Comment: I know this module, but I was hoping it is possible by adding just another line.

Comment: So, I tried the module, but there is no option for the max length of the link text field.

Comment: Seems this is a known issue:
https://www.drupal.org/project/link/issues/1307788 Currently have MaxLength module installed. Can confirm that you still cannot set the character count limit of a link field in drupal 8.